# Axios post is not submitting in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, axios, http-post

I am sending the axios request to laravel login controller.
Axios code

```
         attemptLogin()
            {
              axios.post('/login',

              {email:this.email, password:this.password, remember_me:this.remember_me},
               { headers: {
                  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                          },
               }).then((resp) => {
                    console.log(resp);
                    // location.reload();
                }).catch(error => {
                    this.errorMessage = error.message;
                     console.error("There was an error!", error);
                })
            }
```

Login Controller code

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // return "Login successfull";
        return view('home');
    }
```

I don't what's happening, no error is displaying the console.

Comment: have you checked your network tab if there's any activity?

Comment: Yes, there is no activity

Comment: are you calling the function `attemptLogin` and are you getting anything in your console or network tab?

Comment: Are you using web routes in Laravel? because if you are, for the incorrect creds laravel return you back to your previous page, so it could be that you are getting redirected in your response.
Also try including **csrf** Token.

Comment: Can you provide some detail on how this code is called?

Comment: Actually am calling this method using modal, I click on the modal, it display the sign in form, I put values in it and send these values using axios in authenticate method.

Answer (score 0):

Is the browser showing anything? From what you have pointed out, you should ensure that the request is hitting the login function in the LoginController. You must be hitting that trait class and then your request is processed.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
   use AuthenticatesUsers;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually am answering this my self because I find the exact problem,
Am doing mistake in axios syntax,

**correct syntax is below**

```
attemptLogin()
{
    axios.post('/login', {
    email:this.email, password:this.password, remember_me:this.remember_me
   }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
}
```